# Pipelining vs Batching in Stackexchange.Redis

Tags: optimization, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to insert a large(-ish) number of elements in the shortest time possible and I tried these two alternatives:

1) Pipelining:

```
List<Task> addTasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
    Task<bool> addAsync = redisDB.SetAddAsync(string.Format(keyFormat, row.Field<int>("Id")), row.Field<int>("Value"));
    addTasks.Add(addAsync);
}
Task[] tasks = addTasks.ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

2)  Batching:

```
List<Task> addTasks = new List<Task>();
IBatch batch = redisDB.CreateBatch();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = table.Rows[i];
    Task<bool> addAsync = batch.SetAddAsync(string.Format(keyFormat, row.Field<int>("Id")), row.Field<int>("Value"));
    addTasks.Add(addAsync);
}
batch.Execute();
Task[] tasks = addTasks.ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

I am not noticing any significant time difference (actually I expected the batch method to be faster): for approx 250K inserts I get approx 7 sec for pipelining vs approx 8 sec for batching.

Reading from the documentation on pipelining,

> "Using pipelining allows us to get both requests onto the network
>   immediately, eliminating most of the latency. Additionally, it also
>   helps reduce packet fragmentation: 20 requests sent individually
>   (waiting for each response) will require at least 20 packets, but 20
>   requests sent in a pipeline could fit into much fewer packets (perhaps
>   even just one)."

To me, this sounds a lot like the a batching behaviour. I wonder if behind the scenes there's any big difference between the two because at a simple check with `procmon` I see almost the same number of `TCP Send`s on both versions.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Behind the scenes, SE.Redis does quite a bit of work to try to avoid packet fragmentation, so it isn't surprising that it is quite similar in your case. The main difference between batching and flat pipelining are:

- a batch will never be interleaved with competing operations on the same multiplexer (although it may be interleaved at the server; to avoid that you need to use a `multi`/`exec` transaction or a Lua script)
- a batch will be always avoid the chance of undersized packets, because it knows about all the data ahead of time
- but at the same time, the entire batch must be completed before anything can be sent, so this requires more in-memory buffering and may artificially introduce latency

In most cases, you will do better by avoiding batching, since SE.Redis achieves most of what it does *automatically* when simply adding work.

As a final note; if you want to avoid local overhead, one final approach might be:

```
redisDB.SetAdd(string.Format(keyFormat, row.Field<int>("Id")),
    row.Field<int>("Value"), flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
```

This sends everything down the wire, neither waiting for responses nor allocating incomplete `Task`s to represent future values. You might want to do something like a `Ping` at the end *without* fire-and-forget, to check the server is still talking to you. Note that using fire-and-forget does mean that you won't notice any server errors that get reported.

Comment: Re: the final approach.  If using `SetAddAsync + FireAndForget` + final `Ping`.  Excluding case of unknown transient errors, would the Sets be guaranteed to be added to by the time `Ping` completes?  Or could they arrive out of order?

Comment: @ttugates assuming we aren't talking about "cluster", order should *currently* be guaranteed either way; however, I want to introduce a new opt-in "pooled" mode, where-by we use more connections to avoid big pile-ups when something goes wrong. In that usage: batching would guarantee order, but non-batching could use multiple connections with no order guarantees. That mode would be opt-in, because of this semantic change.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak to the batching but I would recommend against creating `n` number of `Task` items as you are doing based on the dynamic size of some row count in a table.  There can be a lot of overhead on the ThreadPool by creating let's say 100 Tasks and expecting them to provide decent performance.

Comment: Tasks are much lighter than threads.  While the overhead of a Task isn't 0, it's considerably less than the wait time for a network operation.  I've done a async Task.WhenAll(+1000 tasks calling Redis) with no problems at all, and seen it execute more than 50x faster than calling them serially (over a network with 80ms rtt to the Redis Server)

Comment: @PeterDrier have you tested this "at scale" in a proper load testing environment or just a test harness? You would need to have other non-test-related "real-world" traffic running at the same time with your test code, in a NON-local environment, to have good confidence that this will scale well.  Creating so many tasks puts a huge amount of stress on the .NET ThreadPool and is not recommended by the .NET BCL Teams.

Comment: yep, in production, huge calculation engine, multiple data pipelines, thousands of tasks in multiple pods on a few k8 clusters.  You might want to check if your BCL recommendations aren't dated for '23