# Why error No connection is available to service this operation: SETEX while writing to Redis Cache in C# console application and how to solve it

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cache

I am trying to write records from a dictionary with around 5000 records to a Redis cache. But sometimes I get the below exception, I have no clue why I am getting this error, I have checked on the internet but could not find any solution or root cause of this issue.

```
using (ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(_configuration.GetConnectionString("redis_server")))
            {
                IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();


                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in _dictAllData)
                {
                    db.StringSet(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
                }

        }
```

**Exception**

> No connection is available to service this operation: SETEX 747712;
>   IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=0,Free=32767,Min=4,Max=32767), Local-CPU: n/a

**Edit:**

StackExchange.Redis version: 2.0.601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are running out of connections in the pool (client-side). Besides, performance-wise, one set at a time is bad in this case.

You should be using batching or pipelining. See [Pipelining vs Batching in Stackexchange.Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796054/pipelining-vs-batching-in-stackexchange-redis). It has code examples.

And since it seems you don't care about the response, consider `flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget`. See [Pipelines and Multiplexers](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers.html#fire-and-forget).

Comment: I have tried both solutions, pipelining and batching. both giving the same previous error.

Comment: Try downgrading your StackExchange.Redis version to 2.0.519.

There are many reports of this problem with 2.0.571 and later. See https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1120